# AWS Apigateway + Simple System Mangement + Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, integration, gateway, aws-ssm

I'm trying to resolve an ssm parameter throught AWS Apigateway, but i can't find any example.
The cloud formation part where I define the method integration is the follow:

```
Integration:
   Type: AWS
   Uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:ssm:action/GetParameter"
   IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
   PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
   RequestTemplates: 
      application/json: ' 
            {
              "Name": "/dev/configs/xoxo"
            }
      '
```

When I test it in the AWS console this are the logs

```
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Method request body before transformations: 
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request URI: https://ssm.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetParameter
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request headers: {Authorization=**********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************dbf24f, X-Amz-Date=20200810T181410Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=mrvijesndc, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_mrvijesndc, X-Amz-Security-Token=...[TRUNCATED]
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request body after transformations: { "Name": "/dev/configs/xoxo"}
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Sending request to https://ssm.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetParameter
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Received response. Status: 400, Integration latency: 43 ms
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Server=Server, Date=Mon, 10 Aug 2020 18:14:10 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=220, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=c2e56a30-d846-4cd6-b4af-1df95267a3fd}
Mon Aug 10 18:14:10 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"Error":{"Code":"ValidationError","Message":"1 validation error detected: Value null at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null.","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"c2e56a30-d846-4cd6-b4af-1df95267a3fd"}
```

I suppose it is not making the call correctly, could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the SSM API endpoint, when called in this manner, expects to find its parameters in the query string, not in the request body. So the following ought to work: (not tested as such, because I use Terraform instead of CloudFormation)

```
Integration:
    Type: AWS
    Uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:ssm:action/GetParameter"
    IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
    PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
    RequestParameters:
        integration.request.querystring.Name: "'/dev/configs/xoxo'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a long research, google hide this post for me along 8 hours, finally, I found it:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=288118

I hope be helpfully for someone like me in the future

Comment: Any chance you could share the details?  I too am 8 hours deep with no results on the same problem, but Amazon has literally deleted your solution since they don't find it relevant anymore.